# ngModel does not trigger view update the first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Hi I am writing a directive that does some custom input element validation based on a json object that is passed via an attribute directive. 
I am adding an ng-blur and ng-focus in the compile phase binding to two functions in my directive controller. 
however. when I run my code initially the input field does not contain a value altough when I click in it and the blur is triggered I can see in debug that ngModel does contain the value. I am thinking that the view is not updated the first time but I don't understand what is causing it. Here is my code.

```
    'use strict';

angular.module('zendantennesApp')
    .directive('validation', function ($compile, $parse) {
        return {
            scope: {
                validation: '@'
            },
            require: "?ngModel",
            restrict: 'A',
            compile: function(el, attrs) {
                el.removeAttr('validation');
                el.attr('ng-blur', 'evaluateExpression()');
                el.attr('ng-focus', 'assignOriginalValue()');
                var fn = $compile(el);
                return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
                    ngModel.$render = function(){
                    $(element).val(ngModel.$viewValue);
                    };



                fn(scope);
            }
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.originalValue = $scope.ngModel;
            $scope.validationObject = JSON.parse($scope.validation.replace(/'/g, '"'));
            $scope.evaluateExpression = function(){
                console.log(validationObject);
            };
            $scope.assignOriginalValue = function(){
                $scope.originalValue = $scope.ngModel;

            }
        }
    }
});
```

my html:

```
<input validation="{'min':0, 'max':5}" tabindex="45" type='text' class='form-control' ng-model="aanpassing.nieuweAntenne.elektrischeTilt"/>
```

I added a plunkr to illustrate the problem:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1qYxCiSZWHgVeN9CEpxw?p=info

if anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You should probably use ngModelController instead. By using `require: 'ngModel'` instead of having it on scope. Then the ngModelController will be the forth parameter to the linking function, and the stuff you now do in the controller should be done there. Maybe try and read the docs of ngModelController for suggestions on how to go about it

Comment: @Gustav I updated my directive but am still experiencing the same problem. I suspect that their might be another cause for my issue but I am unable to pinpoint it

Comment: @Gustav the $render function is triggering with the correct value wich in my test case is "50.00" yet the view shows an empty input

Comment: @Gustav I added a plunkr

Comment: Ok, so i edited your [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pz5cverAI6iB6STJVjsh?p=preview) some what. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the stuff inside the compile-function. But To me that seems unnecessary. If you what to wait with the validation until blur, you should use ng-model-options, and set updateOn: blur.

Comment: basically, use ngmodelcontroller for validations! and do it inside the link-function, not in the compile and controller. Any questions please tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/pz5cverAI6iB6STJVjsh?p=preview) I provided in the comment seems to work, so I'll put it as a answer.

Instead of using compile on the directive it is possible to use the linking function directly:

```
app.directive('validation', function ($compile, $parse) {
    return {
        scope: {
            validation: '@'
        },
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link:  function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel){
            scope.validation = scope.validation.replace(/'/g, '"');
            var validation = JSON.parse(scope.validation);
            for(prop in validation){
              if(validation.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                setUpValidators(prop);
              }
            }
            function setUpValidators(val){
                switch(val){
                 case 'min': 
                   ngModel.$validators.min = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                      var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                      return value.length >= validation.min;
                   };
                   break;
                 case 'max':{
                   ngModel.$validators.min = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                     var value = modelValue || viewValue;
                     return value.length <= validation.max;
                    };
                    break;
                  }
                 }
            }
            ngModel.$render = function(){
                element.val(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

This will set up validator on the ngModel based on the provided object to the `validate`-directive.
If you want to wait with validating until after the input is blurred you could use `ngModelOptions` like this: `ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"` on the input element.

When doing like this you don't need to add any ng-blur or ng-focus on the element in the compile step.